# AngularJS: ng-repeat and filter inside td

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have some problem in my angular app. If I try use my filter "formatPhone"

```
myApp.filter('formatPhone', function () {
    return function (phone) {
        if (!phone.length) {
            return '&nbsp;';
        }
        var offset = 0;
        var split = [];

        if (phone.length === 10) {
            split.push(3, 3, 2, 2);
        } else if (phone.length === 7) {
            split.push(0, 3, 2, 2);
        } else {
            split.push(0, 2, 2, 2);
        }

        var frag = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            frag.push(phone.substr(offset, split[i]));
            offset += split[i];
        }

        return ((!frag[0]) ? '' : '(' + frag[0] + ') ') + frag[1] + '-' + frag[2] + '-' + frag[3];
    }
});
```

for this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="member in userlist | orderBy: 'name && group'">
      <td>{{member.name}}</td>
      <td>{{member.group}}</td>
      <td>{{member.team}}</td>
      <td>{{member.post}}</td>
      <td>{{member.phones.cdma || member.phones.home}}</td>
      <td>{{member.phones.mob | formatPhone}}</td>
</tr>
```

I get error in console log (angular.min.js:84), it repeats for each element in object 'member', but "formatPhone" function works. How can I fix it?

upd: error like

```
Error: [$interpolate:interr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/$interpolate/interr?p0=%7B%7Bmember.phones.mob%20%7C%20formatPhone%7D%7D&p1=TypeError%3A%20phone%20is%20null F/<@http://localhost/vendors/angular.min.js:6 qd/this.$get</g/s@http://localhost/vendors/angular.min.js:74 Bd/this.$get</h.prototype.$digest@http://localhost/vendors/angular.min.js:100 Bd/this.$get</h.prototype.$apply@http://localhost/vendors/angular.min.js:103 Zb/c/<@http://localhost/vendors/angular.min.js:18 d@http://localhost/vendors/angular.min.js:30 Zb/c@http://localhost/vendors/angular.min.js:18 Zb@http://localhost/vendors/angular.min.js:18 Tc@http://localhost/vendors/angular.min.js:17 @http://localhost/vendors/angular.min.js:201 o.Callbacks/j@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2 o.Callbacks/k.fireWith@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2 .ready@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2 r...
```

Comment: What error are you getting in the console?

Comment: try using angular.js instead of the minified to get better errors while developing. Also is it possible phones.mob is undefined? you may also need to check `if (!phone)` in your function.

Comment: hassassin, thx! I didn't even think about it. It helps: if (!phone || !phone.length)